# How to solve TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array and TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Tags: python, data-preprocessing

I am trying to apply preprocessing steps to my data. I have 6 functions to preprocess data and I call these functions in preprocess function. It works when I try these functions one by one with the example sentence.

```
data = "AN example 1 Sentence !!"

def preprocess(data):
    data = convert_lower_case(data)
    # data = convert_number(data)
    # data = remove_punctuation(data)
    # data = remove_stopwords(data)
    # data = stem_words(data)
    # data = lemmatize_word(data)
    return data

processed_text = []
processed_text.append(word_tokenize(str(preprocess(data))))
print(processed_text)
```

But when I comment out another function, it gives an error. When I comment out the functions one by one, it gives different errors.

These are errors:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'split'

TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array

TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

What could be the reason for the functions working separately but not working together? How can I solve this problem and use these functions to preprocess my data?

Thanks in advance.

Functions that I used:

```
def convert_lower_case(data):
    return np.char.lower(data)

def remove_stopwords(text):
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))
    word_tokens = word_tokenize(text)
    filtered_text = [word for word in word_tokens if word not in stop_words]
    return filtered_text

def remove_punctuation(data):
    punctuationfree="".join([i for i in data if i not in string.punctuation])
    return punctuationfree

def stem_words(data):
    stemmer = PorterStemmer()
    word_tokens = word_tokenize(data)
    stems = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in word_tokens]
    return stems

def convert_number(data):
    temp_str = data.split()
    new_string = []
    for word in temp_str:
        if word.isdigit():
            temp = p.number_to_words(word)
            new_string.append(temp)
        else:
            new_string.append(word)
    temp_str = ' '.join(new_string)
    return temp_str

def lemmatize_word(text):
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    word_tokens = word_tokenize(text)
    lemmas = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word, pos ='v') for word in word_tokens]
    return lemmas
```

Comment: 1. You should really provide a bit more code, it's hard to tell what goes wrong with just the function name.

Comment: Can you share the code of `convert_lower_case()` and at least one of the other functions you're having the issue with?

Comment: 2. It's quite likely that each of the functions accepts and works with a string but returns something that is no longer a string and not accepted by the following functions.

Comment: Yes you're right, but I couldn't find where the problem came from. So I added the functions I use.

Comment: Since I am new here, I cannot use very effectively. I guess I need to tag username @matszwecja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem that can be identified is that your `convert_lower_case` returns something different than it accepts - which *could* be perfectly fine, if treated properly. But you keep treating your `data` as a string, which it no longer is after `data = convert_lower_case(data)`

"But it looks like a string when I print it" - yeah, but it *isn't* a string. You can see that if you do this:

```
def convert_lower_case(data):
    print(type(data))
    new_data = np.char.lower(data)
    print(type(new_data))
    return new_data
```

Output:

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Honestly, you are reinventing the wheel here a bit, because Python already has built-in .lower() function that will return you an actual `string` type object with capitals changed to small letters.
Similiar issues might occur in other functions.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the errors by applying casting.